# Mask input on html does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a mask to my input, but one strange error happens. I have to enter 11 numbers, and my mask have to make it like this: ###.###.###-##. But when I enter the sixth digit my current input become blank. I have no idea what is the problem.

This is my script:

```
function mascararCpf(){
   var cpf = document.getElementById("idCpf");

   if((cpf.value.length == 3) || (cpf.value.length == 6)){ 
           cpf.value += ".";
       return;
   }

   if(cpf.value.length == 9){
       cpf.value += "-";
       return;
   }
 }
```

And this is my input:

```
<label> CPF: <input type="number" autocomplete="on" name="cpf" id="idCpf"   placeholder="Seu CPF"  required onblur="validarCpf()" onkeypress="mascararCpf()"></label>
```

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc9sK/) for convenience.

Comment: Also, where is `validarCpf()`?

Comment: the problem is related to the type of the input. `number` won't accept format like 123,45,6-something

Comment: I changed the input type to text and it works, but the problemm is that it is one mobile aplication, Im using phonegap to build my aplication, and using type = text its not good for the user side. I want to use type = number and mask my input. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
<input type="text"  ...
```

problem with the input type `number`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xc9sK/1/)**

If you want to open Numeric keypad on focus, I would suggest you to use

```
<input type="tel"  ...
```

**[Another DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xc9sK/3/)**

Comment: Yes, it works, but like I said on the up comment but Im building one mobile aplication and using type as text it is not a good idea for user side. Is there a wayto solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to count dots `.` as part of the length. "123.456" is *SEVEN* characters long.

It is a common practice to put several input fields (in your case 4 fields) and to go from one field to the other when the length of the field (3) has been reached.

Comment: Thanks Arlaud, it was inattentive... But using type as number not works, only using text. What I have to do using type as number?

Comment: @Caaarlos well you need to parse the data once it is about to be sent so that only numbers will be kept…

Answer (score 0):

As noted before the input type should be `text`. Furthermore, you should consider that the length of the input value increases after appending a '.' or '-'.

Your html is not valid. The `<label>`-tag should be closed before opening `<input>`.

It's better [not to use inline handlers](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/). You can assign your hander in the script. Using `type="text"` the input value can also be non numeric. If you want the mask-method to check that you should add checking of the inputted value. A tentative method could be:

```
// bind handler to the input field
document.querySelector('#idCpf').onkeypress = mascararCpf;
// the handler method, including a numeric-check for the entered value
function mascararCpf(e){
    var len = String(this.value).length; 
    this.value += len === 3 || len === 7 ? '.' : len === 11 ? '-' : '';
    return isNaN(+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)) ? false : true;
}
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/SdNe5/) demonstrating it all

Comment: Thanks Kooilnc, I changed my code and its works, but the problem is that it is one mobile aplication, Im using phonegap to build my aplication, and using type = text its not good for the user side. I want to use type = number and mask my input.

Using return `isNaN(+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)) ? false : true;` works but, if I click on . or on space, an space is added to the input, and I dont want it too. (It only happens on mobile).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, so I developed the following code. Not 100% yet, but it works.

```
function editMask(mask,element,e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 48 & e.keyCode <= 57 | e.keyCode >= 96 & e.keyCode <= 105 | e.keyCode == 46 | e.keyCode == 8) {
        var v = element.value;
        var N = v.replace(/\D/g,'');
        var L = N.length;
        var r = '';
        var resp = '';
        for (i=0;i<mask.length;i++) {
            if (mask[i] == '_') {
                if (N.length > 0) {
                    r = N[0];
                    N = N.substring(1,N.length);
                } else {
                    r = '_';
                }
            } else {
                r = mask[i];
                if (N.length > 0) {
                    L++;
                }
            }
            resp = resp+r;
        }
        element.value = resp;
        element.setSelectionRange(L,L);
    }
}
```

It's called in the onkeyup event of the input:

```
<input type='text' size=20 id='insPFis_CPF' value='$CPF' onkeyup='javascript:editMask(\"___.___.___-__\",this,event)'>
```

You may want to change the mask format for CNPJ, phone numbers, etc. I hope it helps.